# Move my Wordpress site to a sub-domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I currently have a wordpress site on www.mydomain.com with more than 3500 articles (= V1)

I have developped a new version 100% Ruby on Rails (=V2)

I would like to :

move V1 to archives.mydomain.com

make V2 accessible from www.mydomain.com

What is the best way to proceed without losing all my SEO acquired from V1 (eg : when a visitor will search for an old article on google, It should be accessible from archive.mydomain.com/article-path).

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Ruby expert but you can try something like this:

```
#If page not found
def not_found
    # Check if page that user want to access is available at your old website
    require "net/http"
    url = URI.parse("http://archives.mydomain.com/some-article")
    req = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
    res = req.request_head(url.path)
    # If it's available, redirect user to old website
    if(res.code == "200")
        redirect_to "http://archives.mydomain.com/some-article", :status => :moved_permanently
    else
        raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```